# Smooth.Pspline yields the same results with different spar values

Tags: r, spline

I am trying to determine the best value of spar to implement across a dataset by reducing the root mean square error between test and training replicates on the same raw data.  My test and training replicates look like this:

> Traindataset
>
> t =  -0.008
>   -0.006
>   -0.004
>   -0.002 0
>   0.002
>   0.004
>   0.006
>   0.008
>   0.01
>   0.012
>   0.014
>   0.016
>   0.018
>   0.02
>   0.022
>   0.024
>
> dist = NA 0 0 0 0
>   0.000165038
>   0.000686934
>   0.001168098
>   0.001928885
>   0.003147262
>   0.004054971
>   0.005605361
>   0.007192645
>   0.009504648
>   0.011498809
>   0.013013655
>   0.01342625
>
> Testdataset
>
> t = -0.008
>   -0.006
>   -0.004
>   -0.002 0
>   0.002
>   0.004
>   0.006
>   0.008
>   0.01
>   0.012
>   0.014
>   0.016
>   0.018
>   0.02
>   0.022
>   0.024
>
> dist = NA 0 0 0 0 0
>   0.000481184
>   0.001306409
>   0.002590156
>   0.003328259
>   0.004429246
>   0.005012768
>   0.005829698
>   0.006567801
>   0.008030102
>   0.009617453
>   0.011202827

I need the spline to be 5th order so I can accurately predict the 3rd derivative, so I am using smooth.Pspline (from the pspline package) instead of the more common smooth.spline.  I attempted using a variant of the solution outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14930653/9306954) (using root mean squared error of predicting testdataset from traindataset instead of cross validation sum of squares within one dataset).  My code looks like this:

```
RMSE <- function(m, o){
    sqrt(mean((m - o)^2))
}

Psplinermse <- function(spar){
    trainmod <- smooth.Pspline(traindataset$t, traindataset$dist, norder = 5,
        spar = spar)
    testpreddist <- predict(trainmod,testdataset$t)[,1]
    RMSE(testpreddist, testdataset$dist)
}

spars <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.001)
rmsevals <- rep(0, length(spars))
for (i in 1:length(spars)){
    rmsevals[i] <- Psplinermse(spars[i])
}
plot(spars, rmsevals, 'l', xlab = 'spar', ylab = 'RMSE' )
```

The issue I am having is that for pspline, the values of RMSE are the same for any spar above 0 [graph of spar vs RMSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNv1Z.jpg).  When I dug into just the predictions line of code, I realized I am getting the exact same predicted values of dist for any spar above 0.  Any ideas on why this might be are greatly appreciated.